# encode and decode a string in python

Tags: python, string, decode, encode

I  would like to encode and decode a string with a key for encoding and decoding. Vigenere would do it, but vigenere cannot handle the "-" character and also numbers.
Is there a good solution for this?

Comment: The `encode` and `decode` features of the string library?

Comment: It's called "encryption" and there are countless algorithms. Google it and choose one.

Comment: encode and decode features arent enough good

Comment: convert a string to hex or other , and select `a-zA-Z` by the value ? But it seem too complex. I think the better way is chose other encryption , if you do not insist using Vigenere

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use symmetric key encryption that is safe for passwords, check out the [fernet](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/) package in cryptography. It's relatively simple to use:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

# Creates a random 44 character key in bytes format
k = Fernet.generate_key()

# Class specific to your key
f = Fernet(k)

mybyte = b'Hello, World!'

enc = f.encrypt(mybyte)
dec = f.decrypt(enc)

dec==mybyte
# True
```

The encryption/decryption will only work for this key, which means you can encrypt at runtime (which is a better paradigm)